# How to use AutoMapper to merge array?

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to merge items of array in the object. like python's `zip()`.

I use `AfterMap`, is there a better way?

```cs
#r "nuget:AutoMapper/10.1.1"

using AutoMapper;

public class DeptOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class Dept
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class Staff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<DeptOrder> Orders { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Dept> Depts { get; set; }
    
    public Staff()
    {
        Orders = new List<DeptOrder>();
        Depts = new List<Dept>();
    }
}

public class DeptDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int Order { get; set; }
    
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class StaffDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<DeptDto> Depts { get; set; }
    
    public StaffDto()
    {
        Depts = new List<DeptDto>();
    }
}

var orders = new List<DeptOrder>
{
    new DeptOrder { Id = 1, Order = 1 },
    new DeptOrder { Id = 2, Order = 2 },
};
var depts = new List<Dept>
{
    new Dept { Id = 1, Name = "Dept-1" },
    new Dept { Id = 2, Name = "Dept-2" },
};

var staffs = new List<Staff>
{
    new Staff { Id = 1, Name = "Staff-1", Depts = depts, Orders = orders },
};

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Dept, DeptDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Staff, StaffDto>()
        .AfterMap((s, d) =>
        {
            foreach (var dept in d.Depts)
            {
                var o = s.Orders?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == dept.Id);
                if (o != null)
                {
                    dept.Order = o.Order;
                }
            }
        });
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var dto = mapper.Map<List<StaffDto>>(staffs);
dto.Dump();
```

Comment: You could use a ValueResolver 
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use the context to pass data into the child mapping.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Dept, DeptDto>().ForMember(d=>d.Order, o=>o.MapFrom((_, dept, _,context)=>
    ((List<DeptOrder>)context.Items["orders"]).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == dept.Id).Order));
cfg.CreateMap<Staff, StaffDto>().BeforeMap((staff,_, context)=>
    context.Items["orders"] = staff.Orders);

mapper.Map<List<StaffDto>>(staffs, _=>{}).Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class DeptDtoResolver : IValueResolver<Staff, StaffDto, ICollection<DeptDto>>
{
    public ICollection<DeptDto> Resolve(Staff source, StaffDto destination, ICollection<DeptDto> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source.Depts == null) return new List<DeptDto>();

        return source.Depts.Select(x =>
        {
            var d = context.Mapper.Map<DeptDto>(x);
            d.Order = source.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == d.Id)?.Order ?? 0;
            return d;
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Staff, StaffDto>()
   .ForMember(x => x.Depts, opt => opt.MapFrom<DeptDtoResolver>());
```